# android - I play media file, I pause it, and I resume it, when I go back to activity main my application close

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem with MediaPlayer!!!!
I play media file, I pause it, and I resume it, when I go back to activity main my application close.
my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null; 
            }
              seekHandler.removeCallbacks(run);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have to release the MediaPlayer in `onDestroy()` and `onPause()`.

You don't need the capture the back key press event:

```
@Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDestroy();
  if (mediaPlayer != null) {
   mediaPlayer.release();
   mediaPlayer = null; 
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
  if (mediaPlayer != null) {
   mediaPlayer.release();
   mediaPlayer = null; 
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your Code does not give me solution, but THANKS.
I found the solution. I check the value of "CurrentPosition" of the MediaPlayer when media is paused buy evenement "pause" of the button, if it's greater than 0, I empty the MediaPlayer before starting a new.